# Array split React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to split an array into two arrays.

The problem is main array which I want to split into two is coming from server.And I need to wait until it loads.

Here my code.

This is `useSafeFetch` **custom Hook** which is responsible to fetch data (by the way this is working fine just paste here to show you all code)

```
const useSafeFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [customUrl] = useState(url);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(_ => {
        let didCancel = false;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            if(didCancel === false){
                setIsError(false);
                setIsLoading(true); 
            }
            try {
                const result = await axios(customUrl);
                if(didCancel === false){
                    setData(result.data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                if(didCancel === false){
                    setIsError(true);
                }
            }
            if(didCancel === false){
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        return () => {
            didCancel = true;
        };
    }, []);

    return {
        data,
        isLoading,
        isError,
    }
}
```

I try to write a function which return a two independent array

```
export default _ => {
    const {data,isLoading,isError} = useSafeFetch(`my api`);

    useEffect(_ => {
        console.log(data); // length 11
        const mainA = splitTwoArrays(data);
        console.log("progress",mainA.progressHalf); //length 5
        console.log("circle", mainA.circleHalf); //length 1
    });

    const splitTwoArrays = mainArr => {
        const half = mainArr.length >>> 1;
        let progressHalf = mainArr.splice(0, half);
        let circleHalf = mainArr.splice(half, mainArr.length);
        console.log(mainArr);
        return {
            progressHalf,
            circleHalf,
        }
    }

    return (
        //do something with data
    )   
}
```

This is not worked correctly.

As you can see `main data` length is **11** but function `splitTwoArrays` `split` arrays with wrong way. `progressHalf` length is 5 another `circleHalf` is 1.But `circleHalf` need to 6.

Next try:

using `useEffect`

```
export default _ => {
    const {data,isError,isLoading} = useSafeFetch(`my api`);

    const [progressHalf,setProgressHalf] = useState([]);
    const [newArr,setNewArr] = useState([]);
    const [half,setHalf] = useState(0);

    useEffect(_ => {
        setHalf(data.length >>> 1);
        setNewArr(data);

        const partArr = newArr.slice(0, half);

        setProgressHalf([...progressHalf, ...partArr]); 

    })

    return (
        //do something with data
    )
}
```

This gets into infinity loop when I uncomment this part `setProgressHalf([...progressHalf, ...partArr]);`.

I try to give `useEffect` some dependency but unfortunately this  also  won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this on my own.

```
  const { data } = useSafeFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const [copiedData, setCopiedData] = useState([]);
  const [halfArr, setHalfArr] = useState([]);
  const [secHalf, setSecHalf] = useState([]);
  const [half, setHalf] = useState(0);

  useEffect(
    _ => {
      setCopiedData([...data]);
      setHalf(data.length >>> 1);
      setHalfArr([...copiedData.slice(0, half)]);
      setSecHalf([...copiedData.slice(half, copiedData.length)]);
    },
    [data, half]
  );

  console.log(halfArr);
  console.log(secHalf);
```

And in the end you get two array which created from main data you get from server.

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-snowflake-5slq7)